# Project Euler #3 Python

Tags: python

This is my solution to [Project Euler Problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3). I have written this code for Project Euler but if I put in "49" i get "49". What seems to be the problem?

```
n = 600851475143
i = 2

while (i * i < n):
    while (n % i == 0):
        n = n / i
    i = i + 1

print (n)
```

Comment: Where do you put in "49"?

Comment: I don't know what is `Project Euler #3`. I know I can check it, but it should be in question!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  Project Euler specifically asks people not to post answer to their questions online. It would be poor form for StackOverflow to destroy their website by posting answers to all of their questions.

Comment: @john_science The rule isn't there anymore. Also notice that 49 is the square of a prime number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant set `n = 49`.

Your outer while loop checks the condition `i * i < n`, which is *not true* for `i == 7`, so the outer loop breaks as soon as it hits `7`. Change the `<` to `<=`.

However, your code isn't correct in the first place-- perhaps something like this is what you meant?

```
n = 600851475143
i = 2
factors = []

while (i <= n):
    while (n % i == 0):
        n = n / i
        factors.append(i)
    i = i + 1

print factors
```

Comment: This is wrong. `i` becomes `7` when it is `i*i < n`, but it becomes `8` otherwise.

Comment: Although his implementation isn't fast enough for the actual problem, his problem for the case of `49` is that he prints out `n` instead of `i` at the end.

Comment: @Pound Printing `i` doesn't print the largest prime factor-- try the original code with `n=15`. Of course the answer is `5`, but `i` is 4.

Comment: It is four either way lol. There is also another error with his code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure what this code is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: @kevinsa5 The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Comment: @kevinsa5 those are the directions to project euler, my professor said it was wrong, i changed "print(n)" to "print (i)"

Comment: @CarolineRodgers just changing it to `print i` doesn't solve the problem correctly. The largest prime factor of `600851475143` is *not* 1472.

Comment: @kevinsa5 i understand that, I submitted my answer in before changing the print and i got it correct(6857), but my professor told me it does not work for every number ex: 49. and i'm not sure what else to do. Just a side note, i'm very new to programming, so I'm not a professional at this

Comment: @kevinsa5 that does run, i've just never learned factors.append. Can i get a little explanation of that?

Comment: `factors = []` creates a new list called `factors`, and `factors.append(i)` appends the value to the end of that list. Examples: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `n` you want to print `i`...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written assuming there are more than one factor, but in the case of n=49, it turns out that it has only one factor that is 7. So you can add a line checking whether it has more than one factor, or if not then it should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest way to solve it by finding all the prime factors and then return the max.

Brute force solution took me less then 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean `n = 49`.

Your code isn't right, but the error is small -- change the `<` to `<=` and it works for Project Euler #3.

The problem of the code not working for squares such as 49 still remains though. Here is a modified piece of code that should work for squares as well.

```
n = 49
i = 2
while i * i <= n:
    while n % i == 0:
        x = n
        n = n / i
    i = i + 1
if n == 1: 
  print x 
else: 
  print n
```

Answer (score 0):

finding factors of N only need to check upto √N.

### *First basic solution*:-

- value of N never change

find factors upto √N & store biggest factor.

```
from math import sqrt

ans = -1
n = input() #or directly put 
for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))+1):
    while (n%i==0):
        if i > ans:
            ans = i
print(ans)
```

### *Little optimized solution*:-

- if we change value of N, it iterate less than previous method.
- only need to check % (modulus) of N with primes.

  - **if have prime numbers list, then check/iterate with that only**
  - unless, ignoring even numbers check numbers like 9,15,21... is prime or not, is worthless so...

    - excluding 2 all prime is odd.
    - so after check N with 2, check N with only odd numbers.

find factors upto √N & store biggest factor.
when get factor, divide N until N no have that factor
find the next factor do same process, until N become 1 (no have any factors)

```
from math import sqrt

ans = 2
n = input() #or directly put 

while (n%2 == 0):
    n /= 2

i = 3
while n > 1:
    while (n%i == 0):
        ans = i
        n /= i
    i += 2
print(ans)
```

Comment: your answer may be correct, but it also expected to have some explanation for your answer to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

find prime factors and return largest obviously

```
from math import sqrt
def is_prime(n):
  if n ==2:return True
  if n<2:return False
  if n%2==0:return False
  for i in range(3,int(sqrt(n))+1,2):
    if n%i == 0: 
      return False;

  return True;
n = 600851475143
i = n
while(i>1):
  if is_prime(i) and is_prime(i) and n%i==0:
    print(i);
    break
  i = i-1;
```